# iOS: Proper way of using keychain as a generic mutable dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I need a way to use keychain as a generic mutable dictionary, I've checked a few libraries:

KeychainItemWrapper: looks like one instance of the wrapper is just one key/value pair, as you need to use kSecAttr* for the keys, for a generic dictionary structure, you need to maintain a list of the wrappers, which is not easy.

PDKeychainBindings: this one does not require kSecAttr* as keys, you can you any string, but it does not provide a way to purge all keychain data, you need to know what key's you've used and remove them individually.

Is there any library that uses keychain as a generic mutable dictionary? Most importantly, has the ability to purge all data like `removeAllObjects`?

Thanks

Comment: The proper way to use the keychain as a dictionary is not to use the keychain as a dictionary.  Come on people, there's no magic behind a hash-encrypted SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a single keychain entry and put a JSON string (human readable) or binary plist data (efficient if using NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0) as its contents.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html